# Finding correct site - "Dimensioning personnel resources - examples and resources?"

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation, data-analysis

I am looking for the right site to post this in, and this is what I have written. 
I have considered Data science, Project management, and even The Workforce, but none seem fitting, though I am leaning towards Data science if nothing else.

---

> I'll start off by saying, I am unsure if this is the right place to ask, since there might be a project management, modelling or software site that is better. Also my vocabulary is quite weak in this area

I am in charge of one of my first projects at a new, small firm, where I need to dimension the resources (i.e. model). Once the model has been made I will change certain variables such as what happens if 1000 new product items arrive in stock - how many people should be needed to take care of these. How many people do I need to have ready and how many does it currently take to get the job done? By being able to change variables, the model will be used for future calculations.

I will interview employees on what they do in their work on a daily, monthly, yearly basis and also look at data received from my customer. Based on this data, I will have to estimate how many workers that are indeed actually needed. And if then new activities are added, how many more people are needed as proposed by the model?

**Are there any good resources (books, MOOCs, websites) on how to best dimension your resources?** The main question that will be answered will be, **How many people will be needed in the warehouse, to purchase, to allocate, etc.?**

I'll also be able to ask my boss and colleague plenty of questions and be guided (first project and all). I will be using primarily **Microsoft Excel** to build and showcase the model due to the customer having that kind of access.

---

What I have found so far but have not been able to fully evaluate all.

- Book 1
- PDF

**will add once find right site**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a few problems with the question really.

Firstly resources and books and such are out of the scope of all the sites I know of. They become outdated quickly and attract opinion-based answers.

The other issue is well, what you're asking is *really* broad. You're basically asking something that cannot be asked and answered easily.

You might choose to break up the problem into smaller parts which *could* fit, but you are, as you have hinted, looking at courses and books worth of information.

There's no site that handles *all* the things you need in the manner you have presented here

Comment: That's a very strong point. I must break it down then. Perhaps a better question is along the lines of: **what are some common approaches to personnel resourcing modelling?** And ask (on the side) if there are examples.

Comment: Now, its basically trying to elicit a list, and is still too broad. Any question needs to have a definte, focused answer.

Comment: I'll have to continue figuring it out then. Thanks for the help!